Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') | already used xx && xx.map() to filter, but did not work
I'm fetching data from an API and want to show them as quizs and options, it can show but always have errors:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
code to fetch data is (it's in the parent component):
const [quizs, setQuizs] = React.useState([]);  
React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=11&type=multiple')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const decodeQuizs = data.results.map(result=>({
            question: result.question,
            answers:[result.correct_answer, ...result.incorrect_answers],
            correct:result.correct_answer
      }));
      setQuizs(decodeQuizs);
    })},[])

code to use data and show is(I apply it in another sub-component):
const [showQuiz, setShowQuiz] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
        if(quizs && quizs.length>0){
            setShowQuiz(true);
        }
    },[quizs]);

//...other code here

 {showQuiz &&(
    <div  className='d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>
        <ul>
            {quizs && quizs.length > 0 && quizs.map((quiz,index)=>
                <li  key={index} style={{ display: index === currentIndex ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                //...other code here
</li></ul></div>)}

what I have tried:

GPT said the initial value of quizs is undefined, so I use quizs && quizs.length > 0 && quizs.map to check, but failed, it still has errors;
I quess maybe the async fetch will influence quizs, so I use React.useEffect(func,[quizs]) to control execution, but still does not work.

I wonder which part is wrong. THANKS!

Are you sure the error isn't coming from the code with data.results.map?

I checked the console and yes it is caused by data.result.map, now I know why, thanks!

so I slightly modified the useEffect hook
I am saying hey if the data.results is undefined just return nothing (line 11)
else set the data I want and it works :)


if (!data.results) {
       return;
}





import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Testing() {
  const [quizs, setQuizs] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=11&type=multiple")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data.results) {
          return;
        }
        const decodeQuizs = data.results.map((result: any) => ({
          question: result.question,
          answers: [result.correct_answer, ...result.incorrect_answers],
          correct: result.correct_answer,
        }));
        setQuizs(decodeQuizs);
      });
  }, []);
  let result = quizs.map((quiz: any, index: number) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <h3>{quiz.question}</h3>
        <div>
          {quiz.answers.map((answer: any, index: number) => (
            <div key={index}>{answer}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{quizs && <div>{result}</div>}</div>;
}



this happens as in development mode of react,
the useEffect hook runs twice, I am not really sure why, but the first one fails, maybe because react stops the operation before its fully done which results in an error, but the second one actually succeeds,  which return a valid result and sets the data, the if statement just makes the first one(the first useEffect that always result in an error) have no effect, as a result no errors happen
you can read this article about it
How to stop useEffect run twice since React 18

YES! problem sloved.
I tried some ways to prevent rendering before data fetching was finished, but failed as I did not know how. Thanks for recommending the article!
